# PMD Custom Java Rule not invoked

Tags: pmd

I am trying to create a custom Java rule in PMD, but looks like it is not being invoked.I have placed the rule. xml and the custom class files at the appropriate locations inside PMD lib folder and when I perform pmd checks my custom rule is not being called.And I only get the system out from the constructor

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance , Renjini

Comment: > get the system out from the constructor
That means, you class is actually found and used.
> my custom rule is not being called
Try to override the method "[apply](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/ef3455348603aa25f86894b9930f05f141f44d20/pmd-core/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/Rule.java#L425)" - that will be called once for each file.
It would be easier to help you, if you can share your rule implementation.